# Is regular selection from recurrence also recurrence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, recurrence-relations, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a ring, and $u=(u(0),u(1),u(2),...)$ be a sequence over $R$ ($u(i)\in R$). Let $m\ge1$,  $c_0,...,c_{m-1}\in R$ be fixed elements, and the following law of recursion holds
$$u(i+m)=c_0u(i)+c_1u(i+1)+...+c_{m-1}u(i+m-1).$$
Now, we consider some regular selection from the sequence $u$, i.e. the sequence
$$v(i)=u(l+d\cdot i),\ \ i\ge0,$$
for some fixed $l\ge0$, $d\ge1$.

Is there exists some law of recursion (similar to above) for the sequence $v$. If $R$ is a finite ring, then $u$ is periodic and $v$ is periodic, so it is obviously true. Also it's true for $m=1$. But if $R$ is infinite and $m\ge2$?

Comment: For the Fibonacci sequence it works for say the subsequences of even/odd index. I once needed that and found a way to use the initial recurrence to "push" say the odd index terms onto nearby odd index terms. It wasn't the original recurrence, but it had integer coefficients, Also the same recurrence worked for even as for odd index subsequences, This is scant evidence but suggests there will exist a similar recurrence for subsequences as you want...

Comment: Mr. Newman-- I had previously an erroneous matrix approach, but have replaced it now with a very special case $m=2,\ d=2.$

Comment: This is now also answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779502/the-selection-of-a-linear-recurrent-sequence-over-the-field-is-lrs-too/2786815#2786815 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is commutative, then yes there is one with the same length.

The space of sequences $R^\Bbb N$ is naturally a $R$-module ($(u+v)(n) = u(n)+v(n)$ and $(r.u)(n) = r.u(n)$)

Let $T : R^\Bbb N \to R^\Bbb N$ be the translation-by-$1$ operation, defined by $(T(u))(n) = u(n+1)$.
This is an $R$-linear map, so there is a natural action of the polynomial ring $R[T]$ on $R^\Bbb N$, that is induced by $T.u = T(u)$.

Now in this context, for a sequence $u$, you have

$\forall i, u(i+m)=c_0u(i)+c_1u(i+1)+...+c_{m-1}u(i+m-1) \\
\iff \forall i, T^m(u)(i) = c_0 u(i) + c_1 T(u)(i) + \ldots + c_{m-1}T^{m-1}(u)(i) \\
\iff \forall i, (T^m(u) - c_{m-1} T^{m-1} - \ldots - c_1 T - c_0)(u)(i) = 0 \\
\iff  (T^m(u) - c_{m-1} T^{m-1} - \ldots - c_1 T - c_0).u = 0$

That is, linear recurrent sequences are sequences that are annihilated by the action of a given polynomial in $T$.

So you are given that a sequence $u$ and a polynomial $P(T)$ such that $P(T).u = 0$, integers $d \ge 1,l \ge 0$, and you are asking if there is another polynomial $Q$ such that $(T^lQ(T^d)).u = 0$.
If you find such a $Q$ when $l=0$, the same polynomial will work for $l \ge 1$ so $l$ really doesn't matter here.

Given a sequence $u$, $\{P \in R[T] \mid P.u = 0 \}$ is an ideal of $R[T]$,
so your question now becomes "if $P(T) \in R[T]$, is there a multiple of $P$ of the form $Q(T^d)$ ?"

Now, if $K$ is the algebraic closure of the field of fractions of $R$ and $d$ is coprime with the characteristic, $K(T)$ is a Galois extension of $K(T^d)$ of degree $d$, there is a norm map $N_d : K(T) \to K(T^d)$ so you can simply look at the norm of $N_d(P(T)) = \prod_{\zeta^d=1}P(\zeta T) \in K(T^d)$.
If $d$ is a power of the characteristic, then you can simply take $P(T)^d = P(T^d) \in K(T^d)$.
And you have to do both in succession in the general case.

Anyway, this also works over $\Bbb Z$, so for every $m$ and $d$, there is a big formula that gives the coefficients of $Q$ as polynomial expressions with integer coefficients in the coefficients of $P$. Also, it is enough to have the formulas when $d$ is prime, where you can do the computation of $N_d(P(T))$ over $\Bbb Z[\zeta_d] = \Bbb Z[Z]/(1+Z+\dots+Z^{d-1})$. And we have (from the characteristic $d$ case) $N_d(P(T)) \equiv P(T)^d \pmod d$

Comment: "is there a multiple of $P$ of the form $Q\left(T^d\right)$": yes. The $R\left[T^d\right]$-module $R\left[T\right]$ is free of rank $d$, with basis $T^0, T^1, \ldots, T^{d-1}$. Multiplication by $P$ is an endomorphism of this $R\left[T^d\right]$-module, and thus has a well-defined determinant (being an endomorphism of a free $R\left[T^d\right]$-module of finite rank). This determinant is a polynomial in $T^d$. Moreover, it is a multiple of $P$, thanks to the classical formula $A \cdot \operatorname{adj} A = \det A \cdot I_n$ for any $n \times n$-matrix $A$. No algebraic closures required.

Answer (score 1):

This is for the case $m=2,d=2.$ if $x,y$ are two adjacent terms in the "original" sequence, let the next term be $ax+by.$ Then the term after that is $ay+b(ax+by)$, and the next is $a(ax+by)+b(ay+b(ax+by)).$ Selecting the first, third, and fifth term, to get a subsequence with spacing $d=2,$ and naming these terms $T_1,T_2,T_3$ for convenience, we have
$$T_1=x,\\ T_2=ax+by,\\ T_3=a(ax+by)+b(ay+b(ax+by)).$$
So $T_3$ is $aT_2+bay+b^2T_2,$ and we wish to express $bay$ in terms of $T_2$ and $T_1.$ This can be done by noting that $bay=a(by)=a(T_2-aT_1).$ We get for the two step recurrence (with the above notation for the $T_k$) that

$$T_3=(2a+b^2)T_2-a^2T_1.$$
A quite modest beginning, but the coefficients are in the ring, and the recurrence (which can start at an even or an odd index of the original sequence) is similar to the original recurrence.

Previously I had an erroneous matrix approach, but it may be there is some algebraic operation which would apply to $m=2$ and larger $d,$ or even to arbitrary $m,d.$ If anyone sees such an operation it would of course completely answer the posted question in the affirmative, and I'd be curious to see it.

Note I had to use commutativity of $R$ at a crucial point, and don't know even for the $m=d=2$ case whether for a noncommutative ring the OP's desired recursion can be done.

Comment: I have handled the $m=2$ case in (what I think is) the most explicit possible way in Exercise 5 of https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2016-04-26 .

Comment: Yes, it is similar. But here general case of a ring takes place

Comment: The solution I give does work over any commutative ring; I just stated it for complex numbers because rings have not been defined at that point in my notes. I like your idea of generalizing to noncommutative rings; I really have no guess as to whether the result persists!

Comment: Okay. Over a noncommutative ring, the selection will at least not be purely linearly recurrent with the same recurrence length as the original sequence. For a counterexample, take your favorite noncommutative ring $R$ with two elements $a$, $b$ and $y$ satisfying $bay \neq 0$ and $by = 0$. (For example, $R = \mathbb{Q}^{2\times 2}$, $a = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $b = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.) Now, let the original sequence $\left(u_0, u_1, u_2, \ldots\right)$ start with ...

Comment: ... the values $u_0 = 0$ and $u_1 = y$ and the recursion $u_n = a u_{n-2} + b u_{n-1}$. Then, $u_2 = 0$ and $u_3 = ay$ and $u_4 = bay \neq 0$. Hence, the selected sequence $\left(u_0, u_2, u_4, \ldots\right)$ begins with two $0$ entries but then goes on with $bay \neq 0$. This shows that it cannot be purely linearly recurrent of recurrence length $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is somewhat simpler answer, with the downside that it's less explicit.

Let's consider again the shifting operator $T$ on the space of sequences, and let $k$ be the field of fractions of $R$.

Consider the $k$-vector space of sequences.

$u$ is a recurrent linear sequence if and only if $Span(u,T(u),T^2(u),\dots)$ is finite dimensional.
(if you have a recurrence of order $m$, then that space is obviously of dimension at most $m$. For the converse, if the space has dimension $m$ then there is a relationship between $u,T(u),\ldots,T^m(u)$ so there is a recurrence of order $m$)

So if this space has dimension $m$, then $Span(u,T^d(u),T^{2d}(u),\ldots)$ also has dimension at most $m$ (since it's a subspace).
Let $f_d : R^\Bbb N \to R^\Bbb N$ be the map $f_d(u)(n) = u(dn)$, it only keeps entries with index a multiple of $d$ and erases everything else.
Then $f_d$ is linear, so that $Span(\{f_d(T^{kd}(u)\}) = f_d(Span(\{T^{kd}(u)\}))$ also has dimension at most $m$, which is exactly what we needed to show that the sequence $(u(0),u(d),u(2d),\ldots$) satisfies a linear recurrence of order at most $m$

Comment: what is $k$ from the 2nd and 3rd sentences? Why the characteristic of field of fractions isn't infinite?

Comment: also, we can consruct the field of fractions only if $R$ has no zero divisors. If so, rational field is field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}$ and has infinite characteristic

Comment: Can we use a module $_RR$ instead $_KR$?

Comment: you're right this doesn't work when $R$ has zero divisors. Maybe if $R$ is noetherian you can replace "is finite dimensional" by "is a finitely generated $R$-module" but I'm not completely sure. Though the result is true for any commutative ring because we can have explicit formulas defined over $\Bbb Z$ that make everything work.

Comment: Your salvation works with respect to @darij grinberg comment. Thank you!!!