# The selection of a linear recurrent sequence over the field is LRS too

Tags: abstract-algebra

A Linear recurrent sequence is $u_{i+m} = a_{m-1}u_{i+m-1} + a_{m-2}u_{i+m-2} + ... + a_1u_{i+1} + a_0u_i$, where m is the order of sequence and $a_i$ is integer.

The selection of a linear recurrent sequence is the sequence $v_i=u_{l+di}, i \ge 0$, where $d$ is $u$-sequence step and $l$ is $u$-sequence starting point.
So, it is $(l, d)$-selection.

Prove that if $u$ is a linear recurrent sequence (or LRS) over the field P, $v$ is a LRS over the field P too.

Please write in detail!

Comment: There is a really nice proof using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem. Idea: Let $A$ be the $m\times m$-matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \\ a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{m-1} \end{pmatrix}$. (This is the $m\times m$-matrix whose last row is $\left(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{m-1}\right)$, while its first $m-1$ columns have $1$'s in all cells $\left(i,i+1\right)$ and $0$'s in all other cells.) Now, argue (by induction on $j$) that ...

Comment: ... each $j\geq 0$ satisfies $A^j \begin{pmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_{m-1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} u_j \\ u_{j+1} \\ \vdots \\ u_{j+m-1} \end{pmatrix}$. Hence, each $v_i$ is the $1$-st coordinate of the vector $A^{l+di} \begin{pmatrix} u_0 \\ u_1 \\ \vdots \\ u_{m-1} \end{pmatrix}$. Thus, it suffices to prove that the sequence $\left(A^{l+d0}, A^{l+d1}, A^{l+d2}, \ldots\right)$ is an LRS (this is well-defined, even though it is a sequence of matrices, not of numbers). But this follows from the Cayley-Hamilton theorem applied to the matrix $A^d$. Anyone has time to flesh it out?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Your ideas are very good! But could you give links to the sites (or books), where I can read complete proofs of my approval and the Cayley-Hamilton theorem? Or I would be very grateful if you could write down the proof of my statement here in detail.

Comment: For Cayley-Hamilton itself, see the many references given in [my note *The trace Cayley-Hamilton theorem*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/trach.pdf) (currently in the paragraph under Theorem 2.6), and the note itself. You only need the (famous) Cayley-Hamilton theorem, not the (less well-known) trace Cayley-Hamilton theorem. As for its use... I hope to have more time in the next few days.

Comment: This has previously been discussed at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777724/is-regular-selection-from-recurrence-also-recurrence too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the proof I alluded to in the comments. I will work in a much more
general setting.

Fix a commutative ring $\mathbb{K}$. As usual, $\mathbb{N}$ shall denote the
set $\left\{  0,1,2,\ldots\right\}  $.

> **Theorem 1.** Let $d\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $a_{1}
> ,a_{2},\ldots,a_{m}$ be $m$ elements of $\mathbb{K}$. Then, there exist $m$
>   elements $b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{m}$ of $\mathbb{K}$ with the following
>   property: If $\left(  u_{0},u_{1},u_{2},\ldots\right)  $ is any sequence of
>   elements of $\mathbb{K}$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> \left(  u_{i}=a_{1}u_{i-1}+a_{2}u_{i-2}+\cdots+a_{m}u_{i-m}\text{ for all
> }i\geq m\right)  ,
> \end{equation}
>   then this sequence also satisfies
>   \begin{equation}
> \left(  u_{i}=b_{1}u_{i-1d}+b_{2}u_{i-2d}+\cdots+b_{m}u_{i-md}\text{ for all
> }i\geq dm\right)  .
> \end{equation}

Note that my $a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{m}$ correspond to your $a_{m-1}
,a_{m-2},\ldots,a_{0}$. Note also that I'm not talking about a single $\left(
l,d\right)  $-selection but rather claiming a general linear recurrence that
expresses each $u_{i}$ in terms of $u_{i-1d},u_{i-2d},\ldots,u_{i-md}$ (no
matter what remainder $i$ leaves when divided by $d$); so, in your language,
I'm saying that the $\left(  l,d\right)  $-selections for all $l\in\mathbb{Z}$
satisfy one and the same linear recurrence (for fixed $d$). Finally, the
$b_{1},b_{2},\ldots,b_{m}$ in Theorem 1 depend only on $\mathbb{K}$, $d$ and
$a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{m}$, but not on the sequence $\left(  u_{0},u_{1}
,u_{2},\ldots\right)  $.

The proof of Theorem 1 will rely on the Cayley-Hamilton theorem for matrices.
Let me recall what it says; but first I will need some notations. For any
$n\in\mathbb{N}$, we let $I_{n}$ denote the $n\times n$ identity matrix in
$\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$, and we let $0_{n\times n}$ denote the zero matrix in
$\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$. The ring $\mathbb{K}$ is canonically embedded into
the polynomial ring $\mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  $; thus, any matrix over
$\mathbb{K}$ can be regarded as a matrix over $\mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  $.
If $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ is any $n\times n$-matrix, then the
*characteristic polynomial* $\chi_{A}$ of $A$ is defined to be the polynomial
$\det\left(  tI_{n}-A\right)  \in\mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  $; here,
$tI_{n}-A$ is a matrix in $\left(  \mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  \right)
^{n\times n}$ (that is, a matrix whose entries are polynomials in
$\mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  $). We shall use the following facts:

> **Theorem 2.** Let $A\in\mathbb{K}^{n\times n}$ be any $n\times n$-matrix.
>
> **(a)** The polynomial $\chi_{A}\in\mathbb{K}\left[  t\right]  $ is monic of
>   degree $n$.
>
> **(b)** We have $\chi_{A}\left(  A\right)  =0_{n\times n}$.

Here, $\chi_{A}\left(  A\right)  $ denotes the result of substituting $A$ for
$t$ in $\chi_{A}$.

Theorem 2 can be found in any good textbook on linear algebra. In [my note
*The trace Cayley-Hamilton theorem*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/trach.pdf), Theorem 2 **(a)** appears as Corollary 2.4, and
Theorem 2 **(b)** as Theorem 2.5. Theorem 2 **(b)** is known as the
*Cayley-Hamilton theorem*.

Now, let us prepare for the proof of Theorem 1. Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let
$a_{1},a_{2},\ldots,a_{m}$ be $m$ elements of $\mathbb{K}$. Let $A$ be the
$m\times m$-matrix
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
a_{m} & a_{m-1} & a_{m-2} & \cdots & a_{1}
\end{pmatrix}
.
\end{equation}
Rigorously speaking, this is the $m\times m$-matrix whose $\left(  i,j\right)
$-th entry is
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
a_{m+1-j}, & \text{if }i=m;\\
1, & \text{if }j=i+1;\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for all $i\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots,m\right\}  $ and $j\in\left\{  1,2,\ldots
,m\right\}  $.

Now, consider the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{A^{d}}$ of the $m\times
m$-matrix $A^{d}$. Theorem 2 **(a)** (applied to $m$ and $A^{d}$ instead of
$n$ and $A$) shows that the polynomial $\chi_{A^{d}}\in\mathbb{K}\left[
t\right]  $ is monic of degree $m$. Thus, we can write $\chi_{A^{d}}$ in the
form
\begin{equation}
\chi_{A^{d}}=t^{m}+c_{m-1}t^{m-1}+c_{m-2}t^{m-2}+\cdots+c_{0}t^{0}
\end{equation}
for some $c_{0},c_{1},\ldots,c_{m-1}\in\mathbb{K}$. Consider these
$c_{0},c_{1},\ldots,c_{m-1}$. Define $m$ further elements $b_{1},b_{2}
,\ldots,b_{m}$ of $\mathbb{K}$ by setting
\begin{equation}
\left(  b_{i}=-c_{m-i}\text{ for each }i\in\left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}  \right)  .
\end{equation}
We now claim the following:

> **Theorem 3.** Let $\left(  u_{0},u_{1},u_{2},\ldots\right)  $ be any sequence
>   of elements of $\mathbb{K}$ such that
>   \begin{equation}
> \left(  u_{i}=a_{1}u_{i-1}+a_{2}u_{i-2}+\cdots+a_{m}u_{i-m}\text{ for all
> }i\geq m\right)  .
> \end{equation}
>   Then, this sequence also satisfies
>   \begin{equation}
> \left(  u_{i}=b_{1}u_{i-1d}+b_{2}u_{i-2d}+\cdots+b_{m}u_{i-md}\text{ for all
> }i\geq dm\right)  .
> \end{equation}

Theorem 3 makes Theorem 1 explicit: It specifies what the right $b_{1}
,b_{2},\ldots,b_{m}$ are. All we need is to prove Theorem 3 now.

Before we prove it, we start with a simple lemma:

> **Lemma 4.** Let $\left(  u_{0},u_{1},u_{2},\ldots\right)  $ be as in Theorem
>   3. Let $j\in\mathbb{N}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> A\begin{pmatrix}
> u_{j}\\
> u_{j+1}\\
> \vdots\\
> u_{j+m-1}
> \end{pmatrix}
> =
> \begin{pmatrix}
> u_{j+1}\\
> u_{j+2}\\
> \vdots\\
> u_{j+m}
> \end{pmatrix} .
> \end{equation}

*Proof of Lemma 4.* Recall that $u_{i}=a_{1}u_{i-1}+a_{2}u_{i-2}+\cdots
+a_{m}u_{i-m}$ for all $i\geq m$. Applying this to $i=j+m$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
u_{j+m}  &  =a_{1}u_{j+m-1}+a_{2}u_{j+m-2}+\cdots+a_{m}u_{j+m-m}\\
&  =a_{m}u_{j+m-m}+a_{m-1}u_{j+m-\left(  m-1\right)  }+\cdots+a_{1}u_{j+m-1}\\
&  =a_{m}u_{j}+a_{m-1}u_{j+1}+\cdots+a_{1}u_{j+m-1}.
\end{align*}

But recall that $A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
a_{m} & a_{m-1} & a_{m-2} & \cdots & a_{1}
\end{pmatrix}
$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
A
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{j}\\
u_{j+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{j+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}
&  =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1\\
a_{m} & a_{m-1} & a_{m-2} & \cdots & a_{1}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{j}\\
u_{j+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{j+m-1}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&  =
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{j+1}\\
u_{j+2}\\
\vdots\\
u_{j+m-1}\\
a_{m}u_{j}+a_{m-1}u_{j+1}+\cdots+a_{1}u_{j+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
u_{j+1}\\
u_{j+2}\\
\vdots\\
u_{j+m-1}\\
u_{j+m}
\end{pmatrix} \\
&  \qquad\left(  \text{since }a_{m}u_{j}+a_{m-1}u_{j+1}+\cdots+a_{1}
u_{j+m-1}=u_{j+m}\right) \\
&  =
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{j+1}\\
u_{j+2}\\
\vdots\\
u_{j+m}
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{align*}
This proves Lemma 4.

> **Lemma 5.** Let $\left(  u_{0},u_{1},u_{2},\ldots\right)  $ be as in Theorem
>   3. Let $\mathbf{u}$ be the vector
>   $\begin{pmatrix}
> u_{0}\\
> u_{1}\\
> \vdots\\
> u_{m-1}
> \end{pmatrix}
> \in\mathbb{K}^{m}$. Let $j\in\mathbb{N}$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> A^{j}\mathbf{u}=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> u_{j}\\
> u_{j+1}\\
> \vdots\\
> u_{j+m-1}
> \end{pmatrix} .
> \end{equation}

*Proof of Lemma 5.* We shall prove Lemma 5 by induction on $j$:

*Induction base:* We have
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{A^{0}}_{=I_{m}}\mathbf{u}=I_{m}\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{u}=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{0}\\
u_{1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{m-1}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{0}\\
u_{0+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{0+m-1}
\end{pmatrix} .
\end{equation}
In other words, Lemma 5 holds for $j=0$. This completes the induction base.

*Induction step:* Let $i\in\mathbb{N}$ be arbitrary. Assume that Lemma 5 holds
for $j=i$. We must now prove that Lemma 5 holds for $j=i+1$.

We have assumed that Lemma 5 holds for $j=i$. In other words, we have
\begin{equation}
A^{i}\mathbf{u}=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i}\\
u_{i+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{i+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  .
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{A^{i+1}}_{=AA^{i}}\mathbf{u}  & =A\underbrace{A^{i}\mathbf{u}
}_{=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i}\\
u_{i+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{i+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  }=A
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i}\\
u_{i+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{i+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  =
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i+1}\\
u_{i+2}\\
\vdots\\
u_{i+m}
\end{pmatrix}  \\
& \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{by Lemma 4, applied to }j=i\right)  \\
& =
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i+1}\\
u_{\left(  i+1\right)  +1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{\left(  i+1\right)  +m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  .
\end{align*}
In other words, Lemma 5 holds for $j=i+1$. This completes the induction step.
Thus, Lemma 5 is proven by induction.

*Proof of Theorem 3.* Theorem 2 **(b)** (applied to $m$ and $A^{d}$ instead of
$n$ and $A$) shows that $\chi_{A^{d}}\left(  A^{d}\right)  =0_{m\times m}$.

But
\begin{align*}
\chi_{A^{d}}  & =t^{m}+\underbrace{c_{m-1}t^{m-1}+c_{m-2}t^{m-2}+\cdots
+c_{0}t^{0}}_{\substack{=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}c_{i}t^{m-i}=\sum
\limits_{j=1}^{m}c_{m-j}t^{m-j}\\\text{(here, we have substituted }m-j\text{
for }i\text{ in the sum)}}}\\
& =t^{m}+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}\underbrace{c_{m-j}}_{\substack{=-b_{j}
\\\text{(since }b_{j}=-c_{m-j}\\\text{(by the definition of }b_{j}\text{))}
}}t^{m-j}=t^{m}+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}\left(  -b_{j}\right)  t^{m-j}=t^{m}
-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}t^{m-j}.
\end{align*}
Substituting $A^{d}$ for $t$ on both sides of this equality, we find
\begin{equation}
\chi_{A^{d}}\left(  A^{d}\right)  =\underbrace{\left(  A^{d}\right)  ^{m}
}_{=A^{dm}=A^{md}}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}\underbrace{\left(  A^{d}\right)
^{m-j}}_{=A^{d\left(  m-j\right)  }=A^{\left(  m-j\right)  d}}=A^{md}
-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}A^{\left(  m-j\right)  d}.
\end{equation}
Comparing this with $\chi_{A^{d}}\left(  A^{d}\right)  =0_{m\times m}$, we
obtain
\begin{equation}
0_{m\times m}=A^{md}-\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}A^{\left(  m-j\right)  d}.
\end{equation}
In other words,
\begin{equation}
A^{md}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}A^{\left(  m-j\right)  d}.
\label{pf.t3.5}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}

Now, let $i$ be an integer such that $i\geq dm$. We must prove that
$u_{i}=b_{1}u_{i-1d}+b_{2}u_{i-2d}+\cdots+b_{m}u_{i-md}$.

The matrix $A^{i-md}$ is well-defined (since $i\geq dm=md$). Multiplying both
sides of the equality \eqref{pf.t3.5} by $A^{i-md}\mathbf{u}$ on the right, we
obtain
\begin{align*}
A^{md}A^{i-md}\mathbf{u}  & =\left(  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}A^{\left(
m-j\right)  d}\right)  A^{i-md}\mathbf{u}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}
\underbrace{A^{\left(  m-j\right)  d}A^{i-md}}_{\substack{=A^{\left(
m-j\right)  d+i-md}=A^{i-jd}\\\text{(since }\left(  m-j\right)
d+i-md=i-jd\text{)}}}\mathbf{u}\\
& =\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}\underbrace{A^{i-jd}\mathbf{u}}
_{\substack{=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i-jd}\\
u_{i-jd+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{i-jd+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  \\\text{(by Lemma 5, applied to }i-jd\\\text{instead of }j\text{)}
}}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i-jd}\\
u_{i-jd+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{i-jd+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  =
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}u_{i-jd}\\
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}u_{i-jd+1}\\
\vdots\\
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}u_{i-jd+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  .
\end{align*}
Comparing this with
\begin{equation}
\underbrace{A^{md}A^{i-md}}_{=A^{md+\left(  i-md\right)  }=A^{i}}
\mathbf{u}=A^{i}\mathbf{u}=
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i}\\
u_{i+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{i+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \left(  \text{by Lemma 5, applied to }i\text{
instead of }j\right)  ,
\end{equation}
we obtain
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i}\\
u_{i+1}\\
\vdots\\
u_{i+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  =
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}u_{i-jd}\\
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}u_{i-jd+1}\\
\vdots\\
\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}u_{i-jd+m-1}
\end{pmatrix}  .
\end{equation}
This is an equality between two vectors in $\mathbb{K}^{m}$. Comparing the
first coordinates of these vectors in this equality, we obtain
\begin{equation}
u_{i}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}b_{j}u_{i-jd}=b_{1}u_{i-1d}+b_{2}u_{i-2d}
+\cdots+b_{m}u_{i-md}.
\end{equation}
Thus, $u_{i}=b_{1}u_{i-1d}+b_{2}u_{i-2d}+\cdots+b_{m}u_{i-md}$ is proven. This
proves Theorem 3.

As mentioned above, Theorem 1 follows immediately from Theorem 3.